# Anchored Vwap - How to plot at correct time?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to plot Anchored Vwap from an input time, but the Anchored VWAP starts 1 or 2 bars ahead.

In a 1 hour chart, if I tell it to start 3pm, it will start 4pm.
In a daily chart, if I tell it to start on the 12th, it will start on the 13th.

My chart timezone is UTC.

How can I make the Vwap to start plotting from the specific time I have set?

```
//@version=4
study("My Midas VWAP plus % offset", shorttitle="MY MIDAS", overlay=true)

startBar01 = input(timestamp('14 Apr 2021 00:00 +0000'), '#1 Start Time', type=input.time)

startmidas01 = time >= startBar01 and time[1] < startBar01

v01 = na(volume) ? 1 : volume
cumV01= cum(v01)
CumPV01= cum(hl2*v01)

startV01 = valuewhen(startmidas01,cumV01,0)
StartPV01 = valuewhen(startmidas01,CumPV01,0)

Midas01 = (CumPV01-StartPV01)/(cumV01-startV01)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you're removing the first bar's values from the cumulative totals. You end up with zero divided by zero which returns na. You need to include it by only subtracting up to the starting bar. But not including the first bar of the vwap

```
startV01 = valuewhen(startmidas01, cumV01[1], 0)
StartPV01 = valuewhen(startmidas01, CumPV01[1], 0)
```